# "tool 'builtin.transform' not found for space 'view_3d'"-error message unhides certain vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, weight-painting

tool 'builtin.transform' not found for space 'view_3d' causes a strip of vertices to be unhidden each time I switch into weight-paint.

these vertices belong to the same object, parented to the same armature - as a collection of other connected vertices also are - yet this one strip of connected vertices are specifically being unhidden, unlike the others.

they repeat the error-message: tool 'builtin.transform' not found for space 'view_3d'   each time I switch between the two modes.

they cover up what I want to weight-paint, which is really annoying - how do I make them remain hidden?